# Cannot open Microsoft office document imaging by vba

Tags: vba, modi

I have problem with opening MODI by macro. I want only open it, then select all, copy and paste in my Excel file.

I have:

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Office Document Imaging"
```

Then some Sendkeys.

```
AppActivate "Excel"
```

And Sendkeys to paste.

But my first line doesn't activate my document.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Your question is lacking a [mcve]

Comment: You might try to use the file location of the 'microsoft office document imaging' file, based on the example from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement

Comment: you need to show us that you have tried yourself and you are stuck and need help, I cannot see that